# Onclick refresh div with different values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to reload div (without refresh the page) with different values?

I have this code:

```
$value1 = 'value1';

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#content').doSomthing({
            string: {
                id: '<?php echo $value1; ?>'
            }
});

<div id="content"></div>

<a onclick"">replace with value 2<a/> //when press this the id  will be 'value2'
```

I dont mind to use only `jquery` if i need to, but what way i need to do this?

Comment: [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) can help you fetch value from PHP without page refresh

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger no need of ajax.. it is just text manipulations.

Comment: want value comes from db ?

Comment: @Mr_Green Unless OP is confused about server-side and client-side programming thinking you can get `<?php echo $value1; ?>` from the server.

Comment: @Mr_Green Ah I am not sure, since he mentioned _without page refresh_ and given _different values_ in the question, I assumed he needs to touch back to PHP

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger the page will refresh because the click is happening on anchor tag. so OP needs to use `e.preventDefault` to stop page refresh. that is it I think. but also there is no `href` attribute.. so we can't assume..

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this,

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#anchor').click(function () {
            $("#content").html($(this).html());
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="content">
</div>
<a id="anchor">replace with value 2<a />
```

Comment: no, i need a multyple value changes, so i want somthing diffrent, but it's a idea, tanx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    //stop page refreshing
    var value = this.innerHTML.match(/value \d+/);
    if(value){
        value = value[0]; 
        $('#content').html(value);
    }
});
```

You better assign a class to that anchor element and register the click event as `$("a.className")`.